# Why wont my hover command work?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make a dropdown menu with some simple css and i cant understand why the dropdown wont work i have tried everything i could think of below i have posted the css and the html.
The html code is this

```
   <ul><li>Home</li>
  <li>Crockery</li>
  <li>
    Cutlery
    <ul>
      <li>Kings</li>
      <li>Bead</li>
      <li>Tableware</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Glassware</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

The css is this

```
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E3CAA1;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: agree with @marcelo2605, post your html

Comment: She did, just not very well.

Comment: noticed that.  also noticed she fixed it now

Comment: added a fiddle for her https://jsfiddle.net/uc1pq9no/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this lines:

```
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
```

From `ul li ul{}` selector.

https://jsfiddle.net/uc1pq9no/3/

Answer (score 1):

You have to update ✄ your code with `visibility`, `z-index` and `opacity` as this sample:

```
  ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 12;
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

This code make the submenu visible on **hover the first level menù item**, with the [pseudo-class-selectors](https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/)

**→** Test [here a working demo](http://jsbin.com/yisuxokova/edit?html,css,output).